# Blank screen on application while using Google Map API v2

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

> Could not find class
>   com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence,
>   referenced from method gls.a

is the error we are getting.
We tried changing the API key as well, but still the Same blank screen.

These are our XML files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.khanakhazana"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required, but are
     recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.khanakhazana.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.khanakhazana.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Restaurants"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_restaurants" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Info"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_info" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Map"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >


        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Notify"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notify" >
        </activity>

         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
             android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyC5YXqw5gwVWvr7CLnL4fvvP0pc6MO1Oy4" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding this issue is happening because of three reason

**Reasons**

1) first is lack of internet connectivity

2) second is your google api key is missmatching

3) third if key is ok then your provided package name during key generation is not exact same as your project package name

**Solutions**

for first you need to check your internet conncetion is working or not then you need to go further

for second and third you need to create key with proper steps If your using eclipse then

Eclipse-->windows-->Preferences-->Android-->Build you will get SHA key

Use that SHA key to generate your android key

after pasting SHA key append your project package name by following symbol ";"

for example

**YOR_SHA_KEY;YOUR_PROJECT_MAIN_PACKAGE_NAME** then generate key finally you will get google map key for android use that one hope it will resolve your problem make sure that your using same pakcage name which is your project package name

hope it will solve your problem happy coding :)

Comment: Still showing the same error ! We dont know whats going wrong !!